# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/Product.jsp at line 64

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am new to spring forms and hibernate, I have 3 domain object : Product, Category and Supplier. Whenever I am trying to choose the edit link on the product's page the following exception is coming.The name of categories & suppliers should be shown in the selectlist and the id values should be passed to the properties. Though while the add operation and delete operation is working fine but not the edit link, acutally the same page must be posted back with the values of the specific product which would be selected by the user. Please help.

### Product.jsp

```
            <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
            <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
            <%@ taglib prefix="springtags" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
            <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
                prefix="spring"%>
            <%@ taglib prefix="springtags" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">


            <title>Product</title>
            </head>
            <body>

                <%@ include file="header.jsp"%>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div style="height: 300px; width: 500px; padding: 10px" align="center">
                    <spring:form method="POST"
                        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addProduct" commandName="product">
                        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10" style="background-color: pink;">
                            <tr>
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${! empty product.productname}">
                                        <td><spring:label path="productid"><springtags:message text="Product ID :"></springtags:message></spring:label></td>
                                        <td><spring:input path="productid" disabled="true" readonly="true" /></td>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise>
                                        <td><spring:label path="productid"><springtags:message text="Product ID :"></springtags:message></spring:label></td>
                                        <td><spring:input path="productid" /></td>
                                    </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Product Name :</td>
                                <td><spring:input path="productname" /></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Product Description :</td>
                                <td><spring:input path="description" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Product Price :</td>

                                <td><spring:input path="price" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td>Category :</td>
                                <td><spring:select path="categoryid"
                                        items="${categorylist}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name">

                                    </spring:select>
                                <td><spring:errors path="categoryid" cssClass="error" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td>Supplier :</td>
                                <td><spring:select path="supplierid"
                                        items="${supplierlist}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
                                <td><spring:errors path="supplierid" cssClass="error" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                <c:if test="${product.productid eq 0}">
                                    <input type="submit" value="<springtags:message text="Add Product"/>" />
                                </c:if>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <c:if test="${product.productid ne 0}">
                                    <input type="submit" value="<springtags:message text="Edit Product"/>" />
                                </c:if>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                        </table>
                    </spring:form>
                    <div>
                        <p>${msg}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <table
                            class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                            <caption>
                                <h2>Categories</h2>
                            </caption>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Product ID</th>
                                    <th>Product Name</th>
                                    <th>Product Description</th>
                                    <th>Product Price</th>
                                    <th>Category Name</th>
                                    <th>Supplier Name</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <c:if test="${not empty productlist}">
                                <tbody>
                                    <c:forEach items="${productlist}" var="product">

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>${product.productid}</td>
                                            <td>${product.productname}</td>
                                            <td>${product.description}</td>
                                            <td>${product.price}</td>
                                            <td>${product.category.name}</td>
                                            <td>${product.supplier.name }</td>
                                            <td><a href="product/edit/${product.productid}">Edit</a></td>
                                            <td><a href="product/delete/${product.productid}">Delete</a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </tbody>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${empty productlist}">
                There are no product yet. 
            </c:if>
                            </tr>


                        </table>
                    </div>
            </body>
```

### ProductController

```
                package com.niit;

                import java.util.List;
                import com.niit.cakecuisinebe.model.Category;


                import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
                import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

                import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
                import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
                import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
                import org.springframework.ui.Model;
                import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
                import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
                import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
                import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
                import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
                import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
                import com.niit.cakecuisinebe.model.Category;
                import com.niit.cakecuisinebe.dao.CategoryDAO;
                import com.niit.cakecuisinebe.dao.CategoryDAOImpl;
                import com.niit.cakecuisinebe.dao.ProductDAO;


                import com.niit.cakecuisinebe.dao.*;
                import com.niit.cakecuisinebe.model.*;
                @Controller
                public class ProductController{
                protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ProductController");

                    @Autowired
                    private ProductDAO productDao;
                    @Autowired
                    private CategoryDAO categoryDao;
                    @Autowired
                    private SupplierDAO supplierDao;

                    @RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
                    public String getProduct(Model model) {

                        logger.info("entering showAllGreetings");


                        List<Category> categories=categoryDao.list();
                        List<Supplier> suppliers=supplierDao.list();
                        List<Product> products = productDao.list();

                        if (products!=null && !products.isEmpty()) {

                            model.addAttribute("product", new Product());
                            model.addAttribute("category", new Category());
                            model.addAttribute("supplier", new Supplier());
                            model.addAttribute("productlist", products);
                            model.addAttribute("categorylist",categories);
                            model.addAttribute("supplierlist",suppliers);
                        }

                        return "Product";
                    }

                    @RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method= RequestMethod.POST)
                    public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product ) {
                        logger.info("entering showAllGreetings");

                        /*System.out.println(product.getCategory().getId());
                        System.out.println(product.getSupplier().getId());

                        Category category = categoryDao.getByName(product.getCategory().getName());
                        categoryDao.saveOrUpdate(category); 
                        Supplier supplier = supplierDao.getByName(product.getSupplier().getName());
                        supplierDao.saveOrUpdate(supplier);

                        product.setCategory(category);
                        product.setSupplier(supplier);

                        product.setCategoryid(category.getId());
                        product.setSupplierid(supplier.getId());*/
                        productDao.saveOrUpdate(product);

                        return "redirect:/products";

                    }

                    @RequestMapping(value = "/product/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
                    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable("id")int id, ModelMap model) {
                        logger.info("entering showAllGreetings");


                        productDao.delete(id);
                        model.addAttribute("msg","Successfully Deleted");
                        return "redirect:/products";
                    }

                    @RequestMapping(value = "/product/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
                    public String showEditProduct(@PathVariable("id") int id, ModelMap model ) {
                        logger.info("entering showAllGreetings");
                        Product productToUpdate=this.productDao.get(id);
                        model.addAttribute("product", this.productDao.get(id));
                        model.addAttribute("category", this.categoryDao.get(productToUpdate.getCategoryid()));
                        model.addAttribute("supplier", this.supplierDao.get(productToUpdate.getSupplierid()));
                        model.addAttribute("productlist", productDao.list());       
                        model.addAttribute("categorylist",this.categoryDao.list());
                        model.addAttribute("supplierlist",this.productDao.list());
                        return "Product";
                    }




                    }
```

---

### Product.java

```
    package com.niit.cakecuisinebe.model;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Entity
    @Table
    @Component
    public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int productid;
    private String productname;
    private String description;
    private double price;
    private int categoryid;
    private int supplierid;

    public int getCategoryid() {
        return categoryid;
    }
    public void setCategoryid(int category_id) {
        this.categoryid = category_id;
    }
    public int  getSupplierid() {
        return supplierid;
    }
    public void setSupplierid(int supplier_id) {
        this.supplierid = supplier_id;
    }
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categoryid",nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="supplierid",nullable = false, updatable =false, insertable = false)
    private Supplier supplier;

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category= category;
    }
    public Supplier getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }
    public void setSupplier(Supplier supplier) {
        this.supplier= supplier;
    }
    public int getProductid() {
        return productid;
    }
    public void setProductid(int productid) {
        this.productid = productid;
    }
    public String getProductname() {
        return productname;
    }
    public void setProductname(String productname) {
        this.productname = productname;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    }
```

---

```
    HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB- INF/views/Product.jsp at line 64
    type Exception report

    message An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/Product.jsp at line 64

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/Product.jsp at line 64

    61:                 <tr>
    62: 
    63:                     <td>Supplier :</td>
    64:                     <td><spring:select path="supplierid"
    65:                             items="${supplierlist}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
    66:                     <td><spring:errors path="supplierid" cssClass="error" /></td>
    67:                 </tr> 

......
root cause org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid   property 'id' of bean class [com.niit.cakecuisinebe.model.Product]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/SelectTag.html%20selectTag) of the `spring:select` Tag, the attribute `itemValue` should point to a valid bean property. For what I see at your JSP, that block of code renders the `Supplier` Info... So, does your `Supplier` Class contains an `id` instance attribute (or bean attribute) ?? If not, you should put the right attribute at the `itemValue` tag property...

However, the exception complains about that the Class `Product` does not have an `id` property... Does the `${supplierlist}` expression have Supplier Objects or `Product` Object (you should check this too)...

Comment: Thanks for responding ! ${supplierlist} contains Supplier Objects , and in Supplier class has an id field too.